# Transform JS objects to JSON using transform stream

Tags: node.js, node-streams, nodejs-stream

Note there are many transform streams that do this:

> JSON -> JS

but I am looking to create a Node.js transform stream that can do:

> JS -> JSON

I have a readable stream:

```
const readable = getReadableStream({objectMode:true});
```

the readable stream outputs Objects, not strings.

I need to create a transform stream which can filter some of those objects and convert the objects to JSON, like so:

```
const t = new Transform({
  objectMode: true,
  transform(chunk, encoding, cb) {
    if(chunk && chunk.marker === true){
       this.push(JSON.stringify(chunk));
     }
    cb();
  },
  flush(cb) {
    cb();
  }
});
```

**however, for some reason my transform stream cannot accepts objects to the transform method, only string and buffer, what can I do?**

I tried adding this two options:

```
  const t = new Transform({
      objectMode: true,
      readableObjectMode: true,  // added this
      writableObjectMode: true,  // added this too
      transform(chunk, encoding, cb) {
        this.push(chunk);
        cb();
      },
      flush(cb) {
        cb();
      }
    });
```

unfortunately my transform stream still cannot accept objects, only string/buffer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use only `writableObjectMode: true` on transform stream.

[Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_new_stream_duplex_options)

```
options <Object> Passed to both Writable and Readable constructors. Also has the following fields:
    readableObjectMode <boolean> Defaults to false. Sets objectMode for readable side of the stream. Has no effect if objectMode is true.
    writableObjectMode <boolean> Defaults to false. Sets objectMode for writable side of the stream. Has no effect if objectMode is true.
```

You want writeable part of your transform stream to accept objects because objects are written to it. While strings will be read from it.

Check out this minimal working example:

```
const { Readable, Writable, Transform } = require('stream');

let counter = 0;

const input = new Readable({
  objectMode: true,
  read(size) {
    setInterval( () => {
      this.push({c: counter++});  
    }, 1000);  
  }  
});

const output = new Writable({
  write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    console.log('writing chunk: ', chunk.toString());
    callback();  
  }  
});

const transform = new Transform({
  writableObjectMode: true,
  transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    this.push(JSON.stringify(chunk));
    callback();  
  }  
});

input.pipe(transform);
transform.pipe(output);
```